# Multiple Relationships between same two Models in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Say I have models `User` and `Post`

Clearly, `User` hasMany `Post`

But now I want to have subscriptions.

Do I create a second relationship user/post relationship that is HABTM in addition to the relationship they already have?

Comment: Can you describe the association that you want to have for subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to create the relation User belongsTo Subscriptions.
I do not see that having a relationship HABTM

Comment: But both post and user HABTM each other. Is there a problem with having more than one relationship with the same model?

Comment: if you go to save information in the table in the middle is the best to do: User hasMany JoinTable belongsTo Subscriptions than User HABTM Subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with two different hasMany associations, a new belongsTo association, or a new HABTM association. It really depends on how you want to organize and access your data.

To answer the question you posed in the comments, yes, it's possible to have multiple relationships between the same set of Models. Please read: [Multiple relations to the same model](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model) from the Cake book.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can add more than one relation on the same model. You han have: User hasMany Post
User hasMany Subscription
Post belongsTo User
Subscription belongsTo User

On both direction you can get all users's posts and posts that belong to users.